# por que al señalar con el puntero de mi jinternalframe se deforma

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy buscando una solución a mi problema que es un programa en java con look and feel nimbus, sucede que al entrar en cualquier jinternalframe ocurre error como muestro en las siguientes ventanas
[image: esta es cualquier ventana]

Pero cuando posiciono el mouse y muestra algún tooltip sucede que se deforma toda la interfaz
[image: interfaz deformada]

y despues de este proceso sigue en cualquier posición donde coloco el mouse y no se que hacer para que no se deforme la interfaz, lo agradecere mucho.
Saludos.

Comment: Haz probado poniendo el Formulario con un Gestor de Distribución Absolute?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu apoyo si recién he probado, pero sigue igual sabes a que se debe?

Comment: Estas construyendo el form usando la paleta? O directamente todo por código?

Comment: Realize la interfaz utilizando la paleta para el jdesktoppane,  los jinternalframe y el mismo JFrame y es raro esto en todo programa que abro que tenga que ver con jdesktoppane ocurre el mismo problema imagino que es cuestión de algo refrescamiento no lo se

Comment: Puedes probar si al quitar el Look and Feel sigue teniendo el mismo inconveniente?

Comment: si acabo de probar con un ejemplo sencillo y sigue ocurriendo el error este